# Converting XHR request to axios to request data from GraphQL server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, graphql, axios

I am requesting data from GraphQLHub via XHR:

```
const query = '{ reddit { subreddit(name: "movies"){ newListings(limit: 2) { title comments { body author {  username commentKarma } } } } } }';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("get", 'https://www.graphqlhub.com/graphql?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query), true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onload = () => console.log(xhr.response);
xhr.send();
```

This works. However I tried converting it into axios like so:

```
const query = '{ reddit { subreddit(name: "movies"){ newListings(limit: 2) { title comments { body author {  username commentKarma } } } } } }';

axios({
    url: "https://www.graphqlhub.com/graphql",
    method: "get",
    data: {
        query: encodeURIComponent(query)
    }
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
});
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

Anything wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> `data` is the data to be sent as the request body. Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'.

Since your method for the request is `GET`, the data is ignored. You should use `params` instead. We also don't need to encode our params, since axios already does this for us.

```
axios({
  url: "https://www.graphqlhub.com/graphql",
  method: "get",
  params: {
    query,
  }
})
```

It's probably better to just use POST instead though, since some servers don't allow mutations to be sent as `GET` requests.

```
axios({
  url: "https://www.graphqlhub.com/graphql",
  method: "get",
  data: {
    query,
  }
})
```

Or, better yet, just use a client like [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).